# Object lifecycle in NHibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, lifecycle

I think I'm missing something conceptually regarding NHibernate. I have an `Instrument` object which maps to an `instruments` table in my database. I also have a `BrokerInstrument` object which maps to my `brokerInstruments` table in my database. `brokerInstrumnets` is a child table of `instruments`. My classes look like:

```
public class Instrument : Entity
{
    public virtual string Name { get;  set; }
    public virtual string Symbol {get;  set;}
    public virtual ISet<BrokerInstrument> BrokerInstruments { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }        
}

public class BrokerInstrument : Entity
{
    public virtual Broker Broker { get; set; }
    public virtual Instrument Instrument { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal MinIncrement { get; set; }
}
```

In my unit test, if I retrieve an `Instrument` from the database and then delete it with `ISession.Delete`, it is removed from the database along with the children (I have cascade-all switched on in my mapping file). The `Instrument` however still exists in memory. For example:

```
    [Test]
    public void CascadeTest()
    {
        int instrumentId = 1;
        IInstrumentRepo instruments = DAL.RepoFactory.CreateInstrumentRepo(_session);
        Instrument i = instruments.GetById<Instrument>(instrumentId); // retrieve an instrument from the db
        foreach (BrokerInstrument bi in i.BrokerInstruments)
        {
            Debug.Print(bi.MinIncrement.ToString()); // make sure we can see the children
        }

        instruments.Delete<Instrument>(i); // physically delete the instrument row, and children from the db

        IBrokerInstrumentRepo brokerInstruments = DAL.RepoFactory.CreateBrokerInstrumentRepo(_session);
        BrokerInstrument deletedBrokerInstrument = brokerInstruments.GetById<BrokerInstrument>(1); // try and retrieve a deleted child
        Assert.That(instruments.Count<Instrument>(), Is.EqualTo(0)); // pass (a count in the db = 0)
        Assert.That(brokerInstruments.Count<BrokerInstrument>(), Is.EqualTo(0)); // pass (a count of children in the db = 0)
        Assert.That(i.BrokerInstruments.Count, Is.EqualTo(0)); // fail because we still have the i object in memory, although it is gone from the db

    }
```

What is best practise regarding the object in memory? I am now in an inconsistent state because I have an `Instrument` object in memory which does not exist in the database. I'm a novice programmer so verbose answers with links are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things. Your _session is in effect your unit of work. All the work you are doing here is deleting instrument i. Maybe wrap that code in a using(_session).

When you are doing your assertions. Make a new session to do the retrieval checks.

As regards the "i" object - firstly - don't name it i as that should be only used for loop counters. Secondly, in this assertion `Assert.That(i.BrokerInstruments.Count, Is.EqualTo(0))` the count of i.BrokerInstruments would not necessarily be changed unless your implementation for IInstrumentRepo.Delete(Instrument someInstrument) is explicitly setting someInstrument to null.

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete Instrument by  `instruments.Delete<Instrument>(i);`  Nhibernate will remove the object and its collections from the first-level cache and make it detached and objects remain in memory as detached, if you are need to delete object from memory you need after delete to check if session contain deleted object and  remove manually from memory, you can proceed like this:

```
if (!Session.Contains(instruments))
{
   instruments= null;
}
```

though remember .Net uses a garbage collector, so setting it to null doesn't mean it's gone from memory right away, it's up to the garbage collector to remove it when it gets to it.